# If $G/H$ and $H$ are finitely generated, then so is $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ such that $H$ and $G/H$ are finitely generated, then G is finitely generated also. I'm trying to find a finite set $X$ such that $G$ is generated by $X$, but I have no ideal how to find this set using the finite generator sets of $H$ and $G/H$.

I need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you do this if instead of groups they are vector spaces?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think yes

Comment: Well: exactly the same argument works for groups.

Comment: But what is $G/H$ in vector spaces algebra?

Comment: If you don't now what that quotient is for  vector spaces, how can you do this for vector spaces?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yes, you're right, I realized that the solution in vector spaces is not so easy.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think I've just solved the question can I post an answer to my own post?

Comment: You can, indeed. And you may, too :-)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384565/prove-that-if-h-is-a-normal-subgroup-in-g-such-that-h-and-g-h-is-finitely-genera?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hints: we're given

$$H=\langle\,h_1,\ldots,h_k\,\rangle\;,\;\;G/H:=\langle\,g_1H,\ldots,g_nH\,\rangle$$

Remember now that for all $\,x\in G\,$ there exist **unique** $\,1\le i_x\le n\,$ and unique $\,h_x\in H\,$ s.t. $\,x=g_{i_x}h_x\,$ and, of course, then $\,x\in g_{i_x}H\,$ , so...

Comment: How does the normality of H come into play?

Comment: Otherwise you have no quotient group at all,@user41442...

Comment: I believe I see where this goes but it is not obvious to me that one will get a finite generating set for $G$. What I see here is that $x = ($finite product using a finite subset of elements in $G)($finite product of elements of $H)$. But I don't see why these uniqueness properties force the implication since even though it is a finite product in $H$, if $H$ is infinite for example, it is possible that to generate all $g \in G$ we need to "pull" from an infinite subset of $H$.

Comment: I understand that $G/H$ partitions $G$, and that $x \in G \implies x \in gH$ for some $g$. But I don't see why this $g$ necessarily satisfies your uniqueness argument, only that it is a product of elements in the generating set of $G/H$.

Comment: @DerekLuna Follow the following implications: $$g\in g_{x_i}H\implies\;\exists h\in H\;s.t.\;g=g_{x_i}h=g_{x_i}h_1^{m_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot h_k^{m_k}\implies g\in \langle g_1,\ldots g_n,\,h_1,\ldots,h_k\rangle$$ and thus $\;G\;$ is finitely generated as the above is true for **any** $\;g\in G\;$ .

Comment: I had to write more out for myself (and perhaps for others) to understand better. But I see what is going on more clearly as time as passed. I still don't understand why we can find for every $g$, a $g_{i_x}$ where$1\leq i_{x}\leq n$ such that that equation is true. It just seems you reach these conclusions very "fast" or I am not thinking clearly enough.

Comment: That is because any subgroup $\;H\;$ of a group $\;G\;$  defines a equivalede relation on the group by $\;g\sim x\iff x^{-1}g\in G\;$ , and this is the same as saying that $\;gH=xH\;$ , for all $\;g,x\in G\;$ . The equivalende classes of this equiv. relation are precisely the left cosets $\;g_1H, g_2, H,...,g_nH\;$, which are the elements of the quotient group $\;G/H\;$ in case $\;H\;$ is normal in $\;G\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a finite generating set for $H$. By the normality of $H$, we have for all $g \in G$ that $g = h_{1}gh^{-1}$ for some $h,h_{1} \in H$.

Using the generalized associative law for $G$ and reindexing if necessary we have that

$g = gh_{1_S}=g($finite product in $S)$.

Since $G/H$ partitions $G$ we know that $gh_{1_S}$ is in one of the cosets of $G$ in $H$, meaning that

$gh_{1_S} \in ($finite product of elements in $G$ taken from a (finite subset of $G)=G_{1} )H$ using the fact that in our case, $(gH)^{k} = g^{k}H$ as well as a similar technique to the one above to put $H$ at the end.

Then
$g = ($finite product in $G_{1})($finite product in $S)$ for all $g \in G$ where $|S|,|G_{1}|$ are finite.

Hence, one can take $S \cup G_{1}$ to be a finite generating set for $G$.