# If H is a normal subgroup of a group G such that H and G/H are finitely generated, then so is G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, finitely-generated

> If H is a normal subgroup of a group G such that H and G/H are finitely generated, then so is G.

Proof- Let $H = \langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle$ and $G/H =  \langle y_1H,...,y_mH \rangle$. Claim that $G = \langle x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m \rangle$. Note first that $\langle x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m \rangle \subset G$ by closure of the group G. Let $g\in G$. Then $gH\in G/H$ so that we can write $gH = (g_1H)^{n_1}\dots (g_kH)^{n_k}$, where each $g_i = y_j$ for some $1\leq j \leq m$ and $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $H$ is normal in $G$, we have $G/H$ is a group under multiplication so we can change $$gH = (g_1H)^{n_1}\dots (g_kH)^{n_k} = g_1^{n_1} \dots g_k^{n_k}H$$. By definition of cosets this gives $g^{-1}(g_1^{n_1} \dots g_k^{n_k}) \in H =  \langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle$. Thus $g^{-1}(g_1^{n_1} \dots g_k^{n_k}) = h_1^{m_1} \dots h_l^{m_l}$, where each $h_i = x_j$ for some $1 \leq j \leq n$ and $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. It then follows that $g = g_1^{n_1} \dots g_k^{n_k}(h_1^{m_1} \dots h_l^{m_l})^{-1} \in \langle x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m \rangle$

here is the proof , my question is that why does $g_1^{n_1} \dots g_k^{n_k}(h_1^{m_1} \dots h_l^{m_l})^{-1} \in \langle x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m \rangle$?

my additional question is that, in this line, "Note first that $\langle x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m \rangle \subset G$ by closure of the group G", why is it by closure property?

I have edited my proof to make it more detailed:

here is my updated proof:

Let $H \vartriangleleft G$ such that $H$ and $G/H$ are finitely generated. Then\

$H = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle$ and $G/H = \langle y_1H,\ldots,y_mH \rangle$ ,

where $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} \subseteq H$ and $\{y_1H,\ldots,y_mH\} \subseteq G/H$

\textbf{Claim}: $G = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m \rangle$.

\noindent Let $g \in G$. Then $gH \in G/H$.

\noindent By Theorem 2.8, we can write it as
\begin{align*}
    gH = (g_1H)^{n_1}\cdots(g_kH)^{n_k}
\end{align*}

\noindent where each $g_i = y_j$ for some $1 \leq j \leq m$, $i = 1,\ldots,k$ and $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $k < \infty$.

Since $H$ is normal in $G$, we have $G/H$ is a group under multiplication by Theorem 5.4. So that
\begin{align*}
gH = g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k}H.
\end{align*}

\noindent By Corollary 4.3 (iii), this gives
\begin{align*}
  g^{-1}(g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k}) \in H = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle  .
\end{align*}

Hence
\begin{align*}
g^{-1}(g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k}) = h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l}
\end{align*}
where each $h_i = x_j$ for some $1 \leq j \leq n$, $i = 1,\ldots,l$  and $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $l < \infty$.

Since $h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l} \in H$, we have
\begin{align*}
g^{-1}(g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k}) (h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l})^{-1} &= h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l} (h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l})^{-1}\\
&= e.
\end{align*}

Also, $g^{-1} \in G$. Thus
\begin{align*}
gg^{-1}(g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k}) (h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l})^{-1} 
&= ge\\
e(g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k}) (h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l})^{-1} &=ge\\
(g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k}) (h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l})^{-1}&=g.
\end{align*}

\noindent It then follows that
\begin{align*}
g = (g_1^{n_1} \cdots g_k^{n_k})(h_1^{m_1} \cdots h_l^{m_l})^{-1} \in \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m \rangle.
\end{align*}

\noindent Thus
\begin{align*}
    G \subseteq \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m \rangle.
\end{align*}.

Moreover, by closure property in G
\begin{align*}
 \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m \rangle \subseteq G.
\end{align*}

Hence
\begin{align*}
 G = \langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m \rangle. 
\end{align*}
\
\noindent Therefore, G is finitely generated. \qed

Is my proof correct? Pleasee help me

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To answer your question, you have each $h_j$ is equal to some $x_i$, so in $\langle x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1\dots,y_n\rangle$ Same goes for your $g_j$ and by closure under multiplication and inverses of the group, the product is also in your generated group.

Comment: is the flow of the proof correct? or is there any flaws?

Comment: " Note first that $\langle x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m \rangle \subset G$ by closure of the group G." is useless. It is by definition of $\langle x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m \rangle$.

Comment: "is the flow of the proof correct? or is there any flaws?" Did *you* write that proof, as it seems from this **new question** (which would need a solution-verification tag, and some [focus on your doubts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification)), or did you *receive* it, as it seems from your original question?

Comment: I just recieved that proof , I am still understanding the proof as I am tasked to prove it in detail

Comment: Thank you. I think there are no flaws. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375589) is a post with the same title.

Comment: Instead of $n_i,m_j\in\Bbb Z$ you could as well assume $n_i,m_j=\pm1$.

Comment: thank youu, if there is any corrections or suggestions kindly inform me, I would gladly appreciate it

Comment: Because $(h_1^{m_1}\cdots h_2^{m_2})^{-1}\in H$ by closure. Therefore, we must have $(h_1^{m_1}\cdots h_2^{m_2})^{-1}=(x_1^{p_1}\cdots x_n^{p_n})$ for some $p_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ and because $g$ was some arbitrary element of $G$ then we must have $g=(y_1^{n_1}\cdots y_m^{n_m})(x_1^{p_1}\cdots x_n^{p_n})\space\forall g\in G$.